# pkill can't kill processes with parent process id 1

Tags: process, kill

I want to kill the following processes using

```
pkill "run_tcp_sender.sh"
```

or

```
pkill -SIGKILL  "run_tcp_sender.sh"


    root     14320     1  0  2012 ?        00:00:00 bash run_tcp_sender.sh 138.96.116.22
    root     14323     1  0  2012 ?        00:00:00 bash run_tcp_sender.sh 138.96.116.22
    root     14325     1  0  2012 ?        00:00:00 bash run_tcp_sender.sh 138.96.116.22
    root     14327     1  0  2012 ?        00:00:00 bash run_tcp_sender.sh 138.96.116.22
    root     14328     1  0  2012 ?        00:00:00 bash run_tcp_sender.sh 138.96.116.22
    root     14330     1  0  2012 ?        00:00:00 bash run_tcp_sender.sh 138.96.116.22
```

but it is useless
the processes remain there
what is wrong with my command?

BTW:
 I can use the following command to achieve what I want

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef|grep "run_tcp"|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: What state are the processes in when they can't be killed? "State D" processes generally have to come out of state D (when their I/O finishes) before they look at their signals and state Z processes can't be killed no matter what (short of the parent reaping the child or the admin rebooting the machine). My thinking is that using another command might be just you doing something else for a while and the processes change state on you.

Comment: Does `pgrep "run_tcp_sender.sh"` return the list of processes you want to kill, or does it just return an empty list because the processes are all listed as `bash run_tcp_sender.sh ...`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`pkill` by default sends the `SIGTERM` signal to processes to stop. Here's a list of the signals you can send a process. You can send them by name or number typically:

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2     13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO       30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS      34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

So you're sending signal # 15. If the processes are not responding to this signal then you may need to use signal #9, `pkill -SIGKILL`.

From the [man page of pkill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill):

> -signal
>
> ```
>   Defines the signal to send to each matched process.  Either the
>   numeric  or  the symbolic signal name can be used.  (pkill only.)
> ```

### Issues with pkill

The OP mentioned that he was unsuccessful in getting `pkill -SIGKILL "run_tcp"` to work. We initially thought that the issue had to do with `pkill` potentially killing itself before it had finished killing all the "run_tcp" processes.

But that was hard to accept given a foot note in the `pkill` man page:

> The running pgrep or pkill process will never report itself as a match.

In addition to that, @Gilles left a comment basically saying the same thing, that `pkill` just does not kill itself. Then he gave us a pretty big clue as to what was actually going on.

Here's an example that demonstrates what the OP and myself were missing:

**step 1 - make a sleepy.bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10000
```

**step 2 - load up some fake sleep tasks**

```
$ for i in `seq 1 5`;do bash sleepy.bash & done
[1] 12703
[2] 12704
[3] 12705
[4] 12706
[5] 12707
```

**step 3 - check the running tasks**

```
$ ps -eaf|egrep "sleep 10000|sleepy"
saml     12703 29636  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 bash sleepy.bash
saml     12704 29636  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 bash sleepy.bash
saml     12705 29636  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 bash sleepy.bash
saml     12706 29636  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 bash sleepy.bash
saml     12707 29636  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 bash sleepy.bash
saml     12708 12704  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 sleep 10000
saml     12709 12707  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 sleep 10000
saml     12710 12705  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 sleep 10000
saml     12711 12703  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 sleep 10000
saml     12712 12706  0 21:48 pts/16   00:00:00 sleep 10000
```

**step 4 - try using my pkill**

```
$ pkill -SIGTERM sleepy.bash
```

**step 5 - what happened?**

Doing the `ps` command from above, we see that none of the processes were killed, just like the OPs issue. What's going on?

Turns out this is an issue in how we were attempting to make use of `pkill`. The command:

```
pkill -SIGTERM "sleepy.bash"
```

was looking for a process by the name of **"sleepy.bash"**. Well there aren't any processes by that name. There's processes that are named **"bash sleepy.bash"** though. So `pkill` was looking for processes to kill and not finding any and then exiting.

So if we slightly adjust the `pkill` we're using to this:

```
$ pkill -SIGTERM -f "sleepy.bash"
[1]   Terminated              bash sleepy.bash
[2]   Terminated              bash sleepy.bash
[3]   Terminated              bash sleepy.bash
[4]-  Terminated              bash sleepy.bash
[5]+  Terminated              bash sleepy.bash
```

Now we get the effect we were looking for. What the difference? We made use of the `-f` switch to `pkill` which makes `pkill` use the entire command line path when matching vs. just the process name.

**from pkill man page**

```
-f      The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  
        When  -f  is  set, the full command line is used.
```

### Alternative methods

**kill, ps**

This method is pretty verbose but does the job as well:

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef|grep "run_tcp"|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $2}')
```

**pgrep w/ pkill & killall**

You can use either `pgrep` to feed a list of PIDs to `pkill` or make use of `killall` instead.

#### Examples

```
# pgrep solution
$ pgrep "run_tcp" | pkill -SIGKILL

# killall
killall -SIGKILL -r run_tcp
```

#### References

- [pgrep man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)
- [pkill man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)
- [killall man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

Comment: why SIGTERM doesn't function here?

Comment: Not sure, that signals the application to shut itself down, but it isn't responding. The SIGKILL, is the OS destroying the process, which is a little heavy handed to use all the time. Better to let the application close itself if it can.

Comment: pkill -SIGKILL is useless again! I can only use `kill -9 $(ps -ef|grep "run_tcp"|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $2}')` for killing, strange! do you know why? thanks

Comment: No, `pkill` isn't killing itself, and no, it isn't a matter of which signal is sent. It isn't sending any signal because there's no process by that name.

Comment: @slm [See my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74874/pkill-cant-kill-processes-with-parent-process-id-1/74927#74927)

Comment: @Gilles: Hope you don't mind, I've revamped my answer incorporating the issue you highlighted. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 7):

This is unrelated to the parent process ID. The problem is simply that you are killing all the processes running `run_tcp_sender.sh`, but you have no such processes — the processes you're interested in are running `bash`.

You can instruct `pkill` to match on the whole command line:

```
pkill -f '^bash run_tcp_sender.sh'
```

Another approach would be to kill all the processes that have the script open. That could make collateral damage, e.g. to an editor that was just opening the script.

```
fuser -k /path/to/run_tcp_sender.sh
```

As long as you aren't editing the script as root, killing only root's processes would solve that issue:

```
kill $(lsof -uroot /path/to/run_tcp_sender.sh)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below command is easy and worked perfect for me! The above suggestions didn't work or not efficient (too complicated).

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -f somepattern)
```

I recommend to see which processes match before running kill command

```
pgrep -af somepattern
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use `pkill -f` to kill the matching processes, and why you rather introduce a race condition by first calling `pgrep -f` and then `kill`?

Comment: pkill just sends sigterm and in my case, it did not kill any of my processes. pkill -SIGKILL also did not work. pgrep -f returns the pid of matching processes and as I stated, this worked perfectly while the others did not.

Comment: You will notice that `pkill` _also_ has the `-f` option which makes it match the pattern against the full command line, just like `pgrep -f` does.  The difference being that `pkill` also sends a signal to the matching processes. With `pkill -f -SIGKILL pattern` you therefore send the `KILL` signal to any process whose command line matches `pattern`.

Comment: I tried "pkill -f -SIGKILL pattern" but didn't kill my processes but "kill -9 $(pgrep -f somepattern)" killed all of them.

Comment: `pkill -f -SIGKILL pattern` fails miserably. it even reports `Killed` when pattern is a running process *or* not even a running process. what?!?! the other methods, like this answer, works. something is not right with `pkill`

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill process with "signal 9" , i mean use

```
kill -9 PID
```

normally signal 9 is not recommended for killing databases  engine

if process remains in memory, some i/o lost or process is waiting for i/o completion