# What's the difference between pkill and killall?

Tags: linux, process, kill, process-management

I know that `pkill` has more filtering rules than `killall`. My question is, what is the difference between:

```
pkill [signal] name
```

and

```
killall [signal] name
```

I've read that `killall` is more effective and kill all processes and subprocesses (and recursively) that match with `name` program.  `pkill` doesn't do this too?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252349/what-is-the-difference-between-kill-pkill-and-killall

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) and [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) utilities were introduced in Sun's Solaris 7 and, as [g33klord noted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91530/43779), they take a pattern as argument which is matched against the names of running processes. While `pgrep` merely prints a list of matching processes, `pkill` will send the specified signal (or `SIGTERM` by default) to the processes. The common options and semantics between `pgrep` and `pkill` comes in handy when you want to be careful and first review the list matching processes with `pgrep`, then proceed to kill them with `pkill`. `pgrep` and `pkill` are provided by the the [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) package, which also provides other `/proc` file system utilities, such as [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps), [`top`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top), [`free`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/free), [`uptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uptime) among others.

The `killall` command is provided by the [psmisc](http://psmisc.sourceforge.net/) package, and differs from `pkill` in that, by default, it matches the argument name exactly (up to the first 15 characters) when determining the processes signals will be sent to. The `-e`, `--exact` option can be specified to also require exact matches for names longer than 15 characters. This makes `killall` somewhat safer to use compared to `pkill`. If the specified argument contains slash (`/`) characters, the argument is interpreted as a file name and processes running that particular file will be selected as signal recipients. `killall` also supports regular expression matching of process names, via the `-r`, `--regexp` option.

There are other differences as well. The `killall` command for instance has options for matching processes by age (`-o`, `--older-than` and `-y`, `--younger-than`), while `pkill` can be told to only kill processes on a specific terminal (via the `-t` option). Clearly then, the two commands have specific niches.

Note that the [`killall`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) command on systems descendant from [Unix System V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V) (notably [Sun's Solaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Operating_System), [IBM's AIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aix_operating_system) and [HP's HP-UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX)) kills *all* processes killable by a particular user, effectively shutting down the system if run by root.

The Linux psmisc utilities have been ported to [BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=killall&sektion=1) (and in extension [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/killall.1.html)), hence `killall` there follows the "kill processes by name" semantics.

Comment: The main difference I've encountered is stopping commands of a pattern by a user is `killall -u <username> -r <process>` or `pkill <process> -U <uid>` which makes `killall` a lot easier for me to use.

Answer (score 20):

`pkill` is the one that's worth teaching future generations, both because of the filters you mention and the fact that it's paired with the highly reusable `pgrep`. They kill processes the same way, and neither kills recursively — though with `pgrep`, you can select by session (per-tty, think setsid) or process group (think job control).

Answer (score 13):

One difference is that `killall` takes the exact name of process as the argument whereas `pkill` can take partial or complete name.

You can refer to the following question to know in depth about `pkill`

- [pkill can't kill processes with parent process id 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74874/pkill-cant-kill-processes-with-parent-process-id-1)

Answer (score 2):

`killall` -  kill processes by name. Use the `killall` command to send a signal to one or more processes matching selection criteria, such as command name, processes owned by a specific user, or all system-wide processes.

`pkill` - will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each process instead of listing them on stdout. `pkill` can signal multiple processes like `killall`, but can also use advanced selection criteria that can include any combination of:

Command 
UID
Parent
Terminal

Answer (score 0):

One difference I found just now is `pkill -u` accepts uid. But `killall -u` considers uid as user name.

```
> killall -u 13081
Cannot find user 13081
```