# Why are some processes "killable" by pkill but not killall?

Tags: process, osx, kill

I had over 20 instances of `httpd` (apache) processes running, so I decided to shutdown these. Normally I use `killall`, But when I typed `killall httpd` it just said:

> No matching processes belonging to you were found

I guess thats weird, so I tried `pkill` and were able to kill all the running processes. I have Looked at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91540/79979) but that didn't give me enough information on this. Why is this?

Comment: Doesn't your linked question answer yours? `killall` does exact matching but `pkill` does not. Is that not the answer?

Comment: Apache doesn't belong to you.  It belongs to user www.  Second Service Daemons aren't usually listed as processes