# What is the difference between kill , pkill and killall?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, kill

I am familiar with `kill` command , and most of the time we just use `kill -9` to kill a process forcefully, there are many other signals that can be used with `kill`. But I wonder what are the use cases of `pkill` and `killall`, if there is already a kill command.

Do `pkill` and `killall` use the `kill` command in their implementation?  I mean they are just wrappers over `kill` or they have their own implementation?

I would also like to know how `pgrep` command gets the process id from the process name.

Do all these commands use the same underlying system calls? Is there any difference from a performance point of view, which one is faster?

Comment: Two things: Why use `kill -9` by default?  -15 (please stop) and -1 (modem has hung up, please CLEANLY closed yourself) are much more polite.

Secondly. Beware of using killall on non-linux boxes. It might behave differently. (E.g. on solaris it kills all. NOT FILTERED on process names).

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91527/whats-the-difference-between-pkill-and-killall

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `kill` command is a very simple wrapper to the `kill` *system call*, which knows only about process IDs (PIDs). `pkill` and `killall` are also wrappers to the `kill` *system call*, (actually, to the libc library which directly invokes the system call), but can determine the PIDs for you, based on things like, process name, owner of the process, session id, etc.

How `pkill` and `killall` work can be seen using `ltrace` or `strace` on them. On Linux, they both read through the `/proc` filesystem, and for each pid (directory) found, traverses the path in a way to identify a process by its name or other attributes. How this is done is technically speaking, kernel and system specific. In general, they read from `/proc/<PID>/stat` which contains the command name as the 2nd field. For `pkill -f` and `pgrep` examine the `/cmdline` entry for each PID's proc entry.

`pkill` and `pgrep` use the `readproc` system call, whereas `killall` does not. I couldn't say if there's a performance difference: you'll have to benchmark that on your own.

Comment: `readproc` is not a system call. It's a libprocps library function.

Answer (score 8):

A more practical answer:

- `kill` will send a SIGTERM (terminate a process) signal to the OS for a given process id (e.g. 10341), by default this is SIGTERM. You can actually specify other signals too (e.g. -9 to force terminate)
- `killall` will send SIGTERM to all processes matching a certain name exactly. It also comes wit other goodies such as subsetting by user.
- `pkill` will send SIGTERM to all processes that match a given pattern. It uses pgrep under the hood.

Comment: The answer is a good TLDR summary, but SIGTERM is not a system call but a signal.

Comment: `killall` doesn't just kill names that match _exactly_. For example `killall foo` will also kill a process named `foo_bar`.

Answer (score 3):

kill and killall are tools which provide a way to kill a process. The first by its PID, the second by its name.
pgrep (list) and pkill (kill by default) are tools which provide a way to send message to a process by its name or other attributes
see: http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill
For more info about signals: http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal

Comment: Do you mean `killall` is used to kill a process by its name? and it uses pgrep for this purpose?  and `killall` also kills all the child processes ,? what signal `killall` uses by default?

Comment: ...unless you're on Solaris, in which case `killall` will kill *all* processes you have the right to kill, so that if you're root, you're effectively rebooting the server.

Comment: yep: `killall chromium` will kill the chromium process, `pgrep chromium` will give you the PID list, `pkill chromium` will kill chromium. killall will send by default SIGTERM signal (as pkill)