# pkill in server ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vps, pkill

I used the command `pkill` as **root** on my vps ubuntu, and I got kicked out of the server and can't access it.

This is what I wrote inside the terminal:

```
pkill h
```

**h** is my user in ubuntu

What is the solution?

Comment: You killed al the process with an "h" in its name. Run `man ill` on your terminal for [more info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74874/209677).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to kill all processes belonging to a particular user, use

```bsh
pkill -U user .
```

The `.` at the end matches any process name, and `-U user` restricts the operation to processes belonging to the user called `user`.

To see what processes would be affected by a `pkill` command, you could replace the `pkill` command itself with `pgrep`, and then possibly add `-l` to get "long output" (the process names would be displayed too).

```bsh
pgrep -l h
```

The above commend should show you all commands on the system that contains the character `h` in its name, while the command below  would show you all commands belonging to the user called `user`:

```bsh
pgrep -l -U user .
```

Answer (score 2):

You told us,

> This is what I wrote inside the terminal: `pkill h`

Furthermore, you did this as `root`. What happened here is that you killed all processes containing `h` in the name. This included the master `sshd`, which controls inbound `ssh` requests, as well as all its children that mediate existing connections.

Unless you can log on to the non-graphical console and restart it yourself, you're going to need to arrange for your system to be forcibly rebooted.

I would strongly recommend that you get into the habit of checking the documentation for command with which you're unfamiliar. Here, `man pkill` shows as its very first example a method for selecting only processes owned by a particular user. Applying the example to your situation,

```
pkill -u h          # user "h"
```

Better still, use `pgrep` first to check you've matched the correct set of processes:

```
pgrep -a -u h       # -a shows "all" the command line, for user "h"
```

Or send signal 0, which has no action:

```
pkill -0 -e -u h    # Signal zero, "echo" affected processes, for user "h"
```

Notice that the username must be an exact match, but a process name is a partial match. (This is why `h` in your original command matched `sshd`.)